# Laravel - Creating Custom Classes throws error of undefined

Tags: php, laravel, class

I've been following this short tutorial and wanted to make my own class and call it simple like `classname::methodname`, but without injection.

I get the following error:

> exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with
>   message 'Call to undefined method
>   App\Facades\LiveSearch::getServiceList()'

Link to Tutorial: [here](https://jpmurray.net/using-custom-classes-with-facades-in-laravel-5-f1886b07d87c)

It makes sense and that is why i cannot figure out where the problem lies ..

Comment: as per error, you are calling  wrong `namespace`. Follow your tutorial point by point

Comment: calling this method in a view, as i have understood it I can call it in my entire laravel project right? or just in controllers via importing namespace then i wouldnt have had to do all the service container stuff

Comment: create a folder `app/custom`, create a class, use it in your blade with `@inject`, `@inject('classname', 'App\Custom\Classname')`, call to the method `$classname->method()`

Answer (score 1):

Hey you also need to do the follow up steps to create laravel classes.

I hope this reference on [How to create a laravel class](https://jpmurray.net/using-custom-classes-with-facades-in-laravel-5-f1886b07d87c) is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes i followed every step in the tutorial :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Perhaps try to add some more information about the steps needed, a link only answer is not always useful since the site on the other side might go down.